Use record key type in value function
The following code doesn't work, as the converter function by Typescript should expect a parameter typed Filters. How can we make this work, so that the argument is based on the type of the key of the object?
type Filter1 = {
  type: 'filter1',
  value1: number
}

type Filter2 = {
  type: 'filter2',
  value2: number;
}

type Filters = Filter1 | Filter2;

const converter: Record<Filters['type'], (filter: Filters) => string> => {
  // I'd want: 
  // filter1: (filter: Filter1) => {
  filter1: (filter: Filter) => {
     return (filter as Filter1).value1.toString(); 
  },
  // filter2: (filter: Filter2) => {
  filter2: (filter: Filter) => {
     return (filter as Filter2).value2.toString(); 
  },
}


can you provide what you want to do? like some pseudocode highlighting how you'd like it to work?

You don't seem to want a record, but a mapped type, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Edited the question a bit. I'd like to remove the as conversion ((filter as Filter1)).

Yes, what's in the playground link seems to be good. I think this could solve the problem. Thank you.

One more thing. What if we would want to have the converter partial, so not all filter types will have a function in there. Could this work?

Yes, you could make it partial. Seems out of scope for this question, though. I'm going to ignore it in my answer.

You don't want to use the Record<K, V> type, because the keys and value types of Record are independent of each other. If you want the property type at a key to depend on the key, then you need a more general mapped type.
In particular you seem to be looking for a key remapped type where you iterate over the elements of the Filter union and use its type property as the key:
type Converter = { [T in Filters as T['type']]: (filter: T) => string }
/* type Converter = {
    filter1: (filter: Filter1) => string;
    filter2: (filter: Filter2) => string;
} */

const converter: Converter = {
  filter1: filter => {
    return filter.value1.toString();
  },
  filter2: filter => {
    return filter.value2.toString();
  },
}

That now behaves as desired, and note that the filter callback parameters are contextually types by Converter so you don't have to annotate them.
Playground link to code

Thank you for your answer. I try to use it like this: const myFilters: Filters[] = [myFilter1]; myFilters.map((filter) => converter[filter.type](filter)); But I get this error:
TS2345: Argument of type 'Filters' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. The intersection 'Filter1 & Filter2' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents. Type 'Filter1' is not assignable to type 'never'.

This is a followup question and therefore out of scope here (the right time to get me to consider such things was when I asked above "Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?"). How shall we proceed here?

I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78672056/mapped-type-in-ts-has-conflicting-types-in-some-constituents
