Mapped type in TS has conflicting types in some constituents
I have the following types and I want to create a converter function for them:
type Filter1 = {
  type: 'filter1',
  value1: number
}

type Filter2 = {
  type: 'filter2',
  value2: number;
}

type Filters = Filter1 | Filter2;

type Converter = { [T in Filters as T['type']]: (filter: T) => string }

const converter: Converter = {
  filter1: filter => {
    return filter.value1.toString();
  },
  filter2: filter => {
    return filter.value2.toString();
  },
}

const myFilters: Filters[] = [myFilter1];
myFilters.map((filter) => converter[filter.type](filter));

The error I get:
TS2345: Argument of type 'Filters' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
The intersection 'Filter1 & Filter2' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
Type 'Filter1' is not assignable to type 'never'.

How can this be fixed?

This is ms/TS#30581 and the recommended approach is described at ms/TS#47109, as shown in this playground link. The answer you've accepted is expedient, but not type safe (converter[filter.type] is absolutely not of type (filter: Filters) => string, since that would imply each element of converters accepts both types of Filter, and it doesn't). I could write this up as an answer if you want. Thoughts?

The resolved type of converter[filter.type] is ((filter: Filter1) => string) | ((filter: Filter2) => string). This results in typescript wanting you to pass type Filter1 & Filter2 as parameter - which in this case results in never, because they don't share any properties.
Solution would be to instruct typescript to use super-type instead for the parameter. Something like this:
myFilters.map((filter) => {
    const convertingFunction = converter[filter.type] as (filter: Filters) => string
    convertingFunction(filter)
});


This works (I just edited one typo).

Using a supertype for a parameter is unsafe in general. This is just a type assertion. You know that this is safe by inspection, and it's certainly an easy way to proceed, but it's not the recommended solution to ms/TS#30581.

What would be the solution then?

Yes, it's true, that @jcalz 's approach is more type safe. Altough I would say it is less readable and understandable. Choose the one which suit your project better, I would say.

You can use type assertion:
myFilters.map((filter) => {
  // Switch case can be used aswell.
  if(filter.type === "filter1") {
     return converter["filter1"](filter); 
     // you can index it using filter.type
  }
  return converter["filter2"](filter);
});


Yes, but I'd like to do it in a more "generic" way, so that I don't use if statements.
